# You are not allowed to specify an external URL together with internal

Tags: 9

I created a Drupal Views RSS feed. I used the content link field to create a link to the right node. On the fourth item I added a custom link to an external website. Like so:

```
{% if counter|trim == 4 %}
    {{ custom_external_link }}
{% else %}
    {{ view_node }}
{% endif %}
```

On my local machine this works perfectly but looking at the feed online I get the following error:

```
InvalidArgumentException: The internal path component 'https://externallink.com' is external. You are not allowed to specify an external URL together with internal:/. in Drupal\Core\Url::fromInternalUri() (regel 422 van /home/u74341p91593/domains/handboekbewind.nl/public_html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Url.php).
```

I don't understand what is happening here, who can explain me what is happening here?

Comment: Some code somewhere is doing the equivalent of `Url::fromUri('internal://https://externallink.com')`. `internal/` can't be used with external links

Comment: Ah! Thanks now I understand where to look and what to look for